# How to place a text next to the picture?

Tags: html, css, image, text, paragraph

I want to place 2 pictures, one on top of the page and the other right below it. Then, I want to write something about each picture and I want the text to be located to the right of each picture.

How can this be done?

I am formatting my pictures as following, but the problem is that the pictures are like they were suppose to, but the text appear to be only by first image.

```html
<p style="float: left; clear: left"><img src="image.jpg" height="200px" width="200px" border="1px"></p>
<p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
<p style="float: left; clear: left"><img src="image.jpg" height="200" width="200" border="1px"></p>
<p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
```

Comment: Google haves a lot of exemple.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just use some wrapper divs like this:

```
<div>
    <p style="float: left;"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" height="200px" width="200px" border="1px"></p>
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
    <p style="float: left;"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" height="200" width="200" border="1px"></p>
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/)** example

Comment: I guess I must use divs. I was trying to avoid them and new line characters.

Answer (score 5):

A couple things may help:

1. Your styles don't need to be inline, but I'm assuming you're putting them there for brevity's sake.
2. The images don't need the wrapping `<p>`; the styles can be applied to the `<img>` itself.
3. It sounds like what you really want is two distinct chunks of content, each with an image and some text. I'd suggest placing the image inside of the `<p>` element - it's inline, and `<p>`'s are block. Put the image first, and then float it to the left, as you've tried. That should achieve what you're after.