# Remove space between spans on word wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a text and an icon that I want to show together in a div. The icon should always be right next to the text. When there is not enough space for the text, the text should wrap automatically, but the icon should stay next to the text.

I have tried a few solutions but I always run into the problem that as soon as the text wraps, the span will be much wider than it's content, creating a gap between text and icon:

[image: weird space]

What I want to achieve:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div style="display: flex;">
      <span>Erforderliche Gesamtsumme</span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how this can be solved?
I need a HTML/CSS solution, I don't want to solve this with JS.
I have tried a million things (CSS Grid, display: inline-block, all possible flex properties, ...) and different answers on SO, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: can you share what it should look like with this example (paint example if need be)? should the text be `Erforderliche Gesamtsu<newline>mme` or should the text look like what it currently does and the img be right next to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place a text next to the picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371669/how-to-place-a-text-next-to-the-picture)

Comment: I added the desired outcome.

Comment: you cannot do this

Comment: @magnattic I doubt you can not do this. That is only possible if you place the icon inline with the text. And the propery of HTML element is that it's container must be a rectangular and not any other shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can control spacing by using `padding`, `margin` for the icon

```css
span {
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div style="display: flex;">
      <span>Erforderliche Gesamtsumme</span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9g2yrkza/

Comment: On first try, that seems to work! Thank you :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will always wrap the text, even when the container gets larger.

Comment: @magnattic this won't work, it works only for some very particular case. Check the jsfiddle link I added as comment to understand the issue

Answer (score -1):

For this, you will have to use the flex attribute in your spans:
The larger the value, the more space it takes up.

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <span style="flex:3;">Erforderliche Gesamtsumme</span>
      <span style="flex:2;"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hoffe das hilft dir ;)

Comment: Thanks, this looks okay on first look but actually makes the span of the rocket larger than it's content. If I have a third span in there it will create a gap at the end then. :(

Answer (score -3):

-- white-space: nowrap; remove all empty space.

```html
<div style="width: 200px; white-space: nowrap;">
  <div style="display: flex;">
      <span>Erforderliche Gesamtsumme</span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This overflows the container width. I want the text to wrap if there is not enough space.